# Call ajax function with link

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, joomla

I am trying to create an ajax function with all the data inside the following variable inside the following function: `$item`

```
public function onK2AfterDisplayContent(&$item,&$params,$limitstart)
{
    $view = JRequest::getVar('view');

    if($view === 'item'){
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
        $query = 'SELECT name FROM #__k2_categories WHERE id='.$item->catid;
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $resultado = $db->loadResult();

        echo '<input class=subscribete type=button id='.$resultado.'-'.$item->id.' value="Subscribete" />'; 
    }
}
```

Im not sure if instead of using a `<button>` I should use an html link. The variable `$item` is an object with a lot of information which I want to take to my AJAX for later treating this data...

Comment: Do you want to call the ajax function with that button?

Comment: @johnnyTrak I was told that it may be better using an html link (a href..). But im very new to ajax so im not very sure the best way...

Comment: pass the parameter as get request on the link itself and fetch it in php and display accordingly

Comment: @susheel could you use an example code please?

Comment: `test.com?item=itemname`

Comment: Are you using Joomla 3.x ?

Comment: @Lodder yes, Joomla 3.3

Comment: In which case don't use `JRequest` as it's deprecated. Use up to date coding standards for you database query and have a look at com_ajax and how it works which will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either the anchor or the button element, it depends on your requirement. User always expect web page will direct to another page or popup something after click anchor and trigger a action (form submit, show/hide content...etc) after click a button. Please note you should call event.preventDefault() in click event handler in order to avoid appending unnecessary "#" to url when you're using anchor element as a AJAX caller.

Then you need to store the AJAX call required data to DOM by using custom data attribute in PHP. (Assume that you only need the ID of $item)

```
public function onK2AfterDisplayContent(&$item,&$params,$limitstart)
{
  $view = JRequest::getVar('view');

  if($view === 'item'){
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query = 'SELECT name FROM #__k2_categories WHERE id='.$item->catid;
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $resultado = $db->loadResult();

    //add required data to DOM
    echo '<input class="subscribete" type="button" id="'.$resultado.'-'.$item->id.'" value="Subscribete" data-id="'.$item->id.'"/>'; 
  }
}
```

Final step, register the click event handler of DOM which will trigger a AJAX call.

```
$(function(){
  $(".subscribete").click(function(e){
    if(this.tagName==="A"){
      e.preventDefault();
    }

    //$(this).data("key") will return the value at the named data which is set by HTML5 data-* attribute
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://path.to.ur/url",
      type: "POST",
      data: {id:$(this).data("id")},
      success: function(response){
        alert(response);
      },
      error: function(jqXhr,status,error){
        alert(error);
      }  
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I seem to understand what you are doing but the `$item` has a lot of information inside which I need besides the id... How can I retrieve the rest of this information and also use it in my ajax?

Comment: Why you need a lot of information about $item in your AJAX call? In my opinion, you could just pass the id of the item and get other item information you need in the back-end.

Comment: You mean from the database afterwards?

Comment: I tried your code but its not entering inside the ajax

Comment: Any error in console? I have added the request callbacks (success & error). They can help you to find out the problem.

Comment: Got it working, dont know what was wrong, all the sudden it started to work! XD

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the link in the following way: - on your link you can write

```
  <a href="#" onclick="function()">...</a>
```

Comment: And how do I get the data inside `$item` in the ajax?